# Multidimensional arrays and Addresses

Tags: c

I wrote the following code In c just to check whether the code would break or not:

```
int main(void)
{
    int A [5] [2] [3];
    printf("%d\n\n", A[6]);
    printf("%d\n\n", &A[6][0][0]);
    system("pause");
}
```

Now, the code does not break which was something I was not expecting. When we declare a multidimensional array: `int A [5][2][3]`, doesn't that conceptually mean that A in its first level is a one-dimensional array of 5 elements ( 0 - 4 ) and every element of that array is itself a one-dimensional array of 2 elements and every element of that array is a one-dimensional array of 3 elements? If that concept is correct, how can 
`A[6][0][0]` even exist - since in the first level we only have 5 elements ( 0 based ) .

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing a position outside the array, there is no `A[6]`. That's undefined behavior, and anything could happen.

Note that `A[5]` is a well defined location (past the end of the array), so getting a pointer to it is legal but trying to access that pointer is not. However, getting a pointer to `A[6]` or any other greater index is completely undefined.

Comment: so shouldn't it break instead of giving an integer address. I mean what is that integer address ? Is it some random number which does not indicate the address of any element in the declared array?

Comment: @John Nash: Nope, it could break but it does not have to. When you incur undefined behavior anything could happen, so says the standard word. The entire program could decide to do something totally different, like printing some ASCI art, and still be legal C.

Comment: @John Nash: A[5] is **not** some random address, it is a well defined place in memory: `*(A + 5)`. It is the next spot in memory past your declared array.

Comment: @pb2q: Wouldn't the next spot past the array be `A[5]`?

Comment: @K-ballo yep sorry my mistake: got the declared array dimensions mixed up in my comment and answer. will edit for `int A[5]`.

Comment: So, where will the memory allocation stop. I mean, something like     *(A+12) would also get a spot in the memory ?

Comment: @John Nash: You can't know where will the memory allocation stop, the implementation may very well decide to allocate twice the size of your array (not that any real implementation does it, though). Although some clever implementations in debug mode allocate extra space so they can crash on you if you try to access outside the array bounds.

Comment: How to do I get a pointer to A[5] ? would it be int *ptr=&(A+5) ?..and to access it I would do *ptr ? but how can  I access that pointer since there is nothing in A[5] ?

Comment: You get a pointer to `A[5]` by doing `&A[5]`, but as I mentioned accessing it is undefined behavior. Again, anything could happen, if you are lucky you may get a crash but once you've entered the undefined behavior lands all bets are off.

Comment: @JohnNash  It's easier to understand the C memory model if you think about the days before there was virtual memory addressing and allocation and so on. When C was invented, computers had 56kb of memory that was simply addressed as a 16-bit number from [0x0004 .. 0xE000]. A "pointer" was just a number, and "allocating" a memory address just meant that you had decided to put data there. Thus if you wrote past the end of an array, you were still writing to a valid RAM address, but one that may have had some other variable sitting in it (or nothing of consequence).

Comment: By "computers" above I specifically mean the PDP-11 on which Ritchie invented C.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't do array bounds checking. For `int A[4]`, think of `A[5]` as like pointer arithmetic: `*(A + 5)`.

Even if `A` has only been declared with 5 elements (0-4), C will allow you to reference memory outside the declared bounds of your array, using `A`.

The result of this access is undefined. If you read `A[5]`, you might get garbage; if you write `A[5]`, i.e. `A[5] = 13`, you may corrupt another allocated block of memory.

The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_arithmetic#C_arrays) is a pretty good start for understanding this, but I recommend that you pick up a copy of [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), read it, and do all the exercises.